# Classical mechanics in coadjoint orbits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, group-theory, representation-theory

We know that [coadjoint orbits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coadjoint+orbit) are symplectic manifolds, and they can be used to find unitary representations of Lie groups and stuff, and it's also related to quantization. However, is it true that given a classical mechanics system, you could always realize this as a coadjoint orbit of some Lie group? And would finding its corresponding representation be be equivalent with finding its corresponding quantization?

Answer (score 1):

There is a general [result](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6cdd/91012b8d62a12b22288ccc428e7d1868567d.pdf)  by Patrick Iglesias-Zemmour that every symplectic manifold is a coadjoint orbit of its symplectomorphism group.

However, from the quantization point of view, this result is not constructive because the symplectomorphism group is infinite dimensional; and in addition, not much is known about the geometry and topology of symplectomorphism groups in general, let alone its representation theory. Please see the following review by [McDuff](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/73c8/36f706af797b727a6a00277d668e230a0e25.pdf).

In the case of standard coadjoint orbits of some compact group $G$, then $G$ itself is a subgroup of the group of symplectomorphisms. In this case the geometric quantization program can always be carried out to quantize the coadjoint orbit. However, even in the case of non-compact semisimple Lie groups and solvable Lie groups, there are some trouble in the method of orbits, please see [Kirillov](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1999-36-04/S0273-0979-99-00849-6/S0273-0979-99-00849-6.pdf).